# Invoke Jupyter Notebook from a webapplication in cloud

Tags: apache-spark, remote-access, jupyter

I have a jupyter notebook that performs some computing using Spark on an AWS EMR cluster. I have it configured so that I can access via the browser and run my notebook for machine learning. **I am looking for the solutions that will allow me**, to be able to trigger the notebook either on a schedule or on demand from a web application that is running on AWS.

I have looked at **[nbconvert](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html)** that allows to run a notebook from terminal and perform conversions to various formats. However, it's not clear to me how I would trigger this from the web application.

*Thinking out loud*
It seems like I would want to have the EMR cluster up and running and then may be have the web application invoke a script on the cluster that would use **nbconvert** and run the notebook?

Comment: "from a web application" -- Too vague. What is this "web application" running? It's just Amazon Linux, right? So you can try to run `nbconvert` from anywhere with Python & Jupyter installed

Comment: What exactly would happen if an external event "ran the notebook"?  For example, would another browser window with that notebook open update its cells? It sounds like you are trying to save a step between protoyping with jupyter and making a production version and perhaps ignoring that there would have to be differences between the notebook prototype and the production version, because they have different requirements and audiences.

Comment: @cricket_007 - Yes, the web application has Amazon Linux. However, if you install Python & Jupyter and run locally its running locally correct? The operation I am performing needs a few nodes in the EMR cluster as it does some processing

Comment: This runs remotely... `spark-submit --master <address_here>`. You need to configure the Jupyter kernel to set the master address. I would suggest rather extracting your noteboook code into `.py` files that you submit to spark

Comment: @cricket_007 I have already converted the notebook to a .py - but I guess I wasn't clear on how I would go about using it. Since jupyter notebooks are just a web interface - I guess I could just run it against an EMR cluster using spark-submit as you suggested?

Comment: Yes, you can. Jupyter is only a front-end yes. Any time you "submit" a cell, it still runs a Python interpreter environment in the background.

Comment: @cricket_007 - We run the notebook against a spark shell that has a bunch of dependencies pre-loaded. This allows us to run some heavy queries. If I just use spark-submit, I would essentially have to pass all of these again to start a new job. Instead, IF there was a spark job already running on a cluster - is there a way to pass a .py file or a zip of the .py files to be executed against?

Comment: We use Zeppelin notebooks and looks like I may be able to leverage the REST API - https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.0/rest-api/rest-notebook.html#create-a-new-paragraph

Comment: Zeppelin still uses a configurable kernel like Jupyter last time I checked. I do not think `nbconvert` works with Zeppelin notebooks, though. And I have no experience with submitting additional code to an existing running application because that wouldn't make sense. The new code / variables couldn't be referenced by the existing application and would need to be "injected" into the running executor JVMs

Answer (score 2):

We have written a simple extension to Jupyter notebook server that lets you execute notebooks with HTTP requests: https://github.com/EniramLtd/jupyter-invoke.

[Jupyter Kernel Gateway](http://jupyter-kernel-gateway.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) also provides similar functionality.